# How to create a version 3 or version 5 UUID implementation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, uuid

Is there a library available that does that?
I referred to this answer but it only has other versions not version 3 or 5.

[Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript/21963136#21963136)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful uuid implementation in JS is the package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

```
why?
weekly downloads
13,478,626
```

also:
Support for version 1, 3, 4 and 5 UUIDs

In the future, you could search NPM yourself and take as a reliable metric the weekly downloads.